# Cannot access AWS instance out of country

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I set up an AWS EC2 instance before heading to Germany, which worked just fine. Now that I have arrived, I can't seem to access it. NMAP says that 80/tcp is filtered. Is this Germany blocking me or Amazon?

Comment: You need to elaborate more on the issue and tell us about your setup. For example, what rules do you have in your security group? It's impossible to know what the issue is with so little information.

Comment: Can you access the administration dashboard from AWS?

Comment: The downvote on your brand new first post may be from SE network convention (discussion: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210840/should-stack-overflow-and-stack-exchange-in-general-be-awarding-as-for-effor). To me basic knowledge is demonstrated by nmap, but maybe not as much on AWS or Stack*. This is a useful network, so if Jamieson's answer seems appropriate (it is from what I know, but I also can't tell from the question), if it's correct and you mark it (otherwise please try the tour or expand as Bazze suggests), I'll gladly contribute too.

Comment: I can say for sure that "Germany" isn't blocking AWS as I'm working every day with my 100+ instances on AWS and I'm a German guy in Germany ;-)
So this has to be something you did wrong on the security group configuration.

Answer (score 3):

Often security groups for newly-created instances are configured to only allow traffic from a single IP.

You may need to log into the AWS console (https://console.aws.amazon.com/console/home) and edit the EC2 security group for that instance to explicitly allow access on either SSH (Linux) or RDP (Windows) ports from your new IP address (or subnet) in Germany.

Additional documentation is available here:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/authorizing-access-to-an-instance.html

Comment: +1 for considered / experienced answer to a detail-tough question.

Comment: thx @cmdqueue :)